# Segmentation fault when printing images with transparency and -nodisplay option

Tags: linux, matlab, segmentation-fault, alpha-transparency

I'm running MATLAB 2012a on Linux's command line with -nodisplay option. When I run my code I get a segmentation fault. The following piece of code reproduce my error. The error is produced when the plot has transparencies. If I comment out this line out alpha(h2,0.5);, it works fine.

```
    filename ='mypng.png'; 
    Image1 = imread('peppers.png');
    [row,col,~]=size(Image1);
    Image2 = ones(row,col,3);
    f=figure(1);set(f,'Visible','off'); 
    h1=imagesc(Image1);
    hold on 
    h2=imagesc(Image2);
    alpha(h2,0.5);
    axis off;
    print(f,'-dpng',filename);
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: What's your OS? It works fine for me.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04. Note that this runs for me on the MATLAB's desktop. However, It crashes  when MATLAB run on the command line with -nodisplay option

Comment: Did you try with `opengl software`?

Comment: No, I didn't. My code is written in MATLAB. This is a dummy example that reproduces my error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question, just in case someone else run into this problem (although it's improbable). The purpose of running matlab in terminal with -nodisplay option is because I work on a headless server.

The use of -nodesktop instead of -nodisplay does the trick.